# Objective C, A Question about thread

Tags: objective-c

I have a couple question..First of all, what is the best way to implement an inner class that shown in the java code below? (implementing a protocol like an interface in Java)

```
 public class MembershipControl {
      public MembershipControl(){
           //do something here...
           sendMessage sendMsgThread = new SendMessageThread();
           Thread sendeMsgThreadInst = new Thread(sendMsgThread);
           sendMsgThreadInst.start();
      }

      public class sendMessageThread implements Runnable {
      public void run() {
           while (isActive) {
                //do something here
           }
      }
 }
```

Also, as you guys might noticed, the inner class this case will be run on a separate thread.
So I have a Java code like this inside of the constructor

```
 sendMessage sendMsgThread = new SendMessageThread();
 Thread sendeMsgThreadInst = new Thread(sendMsgThread);
 sendMsgThreadInst.start();
```

I have used something like this in Objective C to spawn a new thread..In the java code, the inner class has a while loop and it runs forever as long as isActive, boolean type variable, is true. Can I just set up an while loop with a boolean type variable like shown in Java code to run the loop forever as long as the boolean variable is true in objective C? Am I supposed to use CFRunLoop?

```
 [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(a method here:) toTarget:self withObject: an object to be passed];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to port code from one language & API to another line-by-line, construct-by-construct, is a losing battle.

You need to start at a relatively abstract level, read through the [various](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html) [excellent](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) [programming](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) guides related to your targeted platform and then solve your problem in whatever fashion best fits that platform.

(Not saying that you are making the aforementioned mistake -- just making sure that others that might read this don't!)

In particular, the [Concurrency Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) is likely going to be highly applicable (assuming a working knowledge of Objective-C).

Specifically, what you want to avoid are spawning lots of threads -- no need because you have GCD and NSOperation instead -- and anything that resembles:

```
while(stillRunning) {
    ... do something
}
```

In particular, the latter construct alludes to a polling construct.  Polling is bad;  it eats CPU, battery, and often makes the app less responsive.  The general model on Mac OS X and iOS is to set up some kind of handler -- a dispatch source, run loop event handler, etc... -- and then use CPU only when responding a response-worthy event.